# Populate ConcurrentHashMap from a single thread and then read from multiple threads without any race condition?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety, concurrenthashmap

I have a class in which I have a `ConcurrentHashMap` which is updated by a single thread every 30 seconds and then I have multiple reader threads reading from the same `ConcurrentHashMap` by calling `getNextSocket()` method.

Below is my singleton class which on the initialization calls `connectToSockets()` method to populate my `ConcurrentHashMap` and then starts a background thread which updates the same map every 30 second by calling `updateSockets()` method.

And then from multiple threads I am calling `getNextSocket()` method to get next available live socket which uses same map to get the information out. I also have `SocketInfo` class which is immutable which contains the state of all the sockets whether they are  live or not.

```
public class SocketHolder {
  private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
  private final Map<DatacenterEnum, List<SocketInfo>> liveSocketsByDc = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

  // Lazy Loaded Singleton Pattern
  private static class Holder {
    private static final SocketHolder INSTANCE = new SocketHolder();
  }

  public static SocketHolder getInstance() {
    return Holder.INSTANCE;
  }

  private SocketHolder() {
   connectToSockets();
   scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        updateSockets();
      }
    }, 30, 30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  }

  private void connectToSockets() {
    Map<DatacenterEnum, ImmutableList<String>> socketsByDc = TestUtils.SERVERS;
    for (Map.Entry<DatacenterEnum, ImmutableList<String>> entry : socketsByDc.entrySet()) {
      List<SocketInfo> addedColoSockets = connect(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue(), ZMQ.PUSH);
      liveSocketsByDc.put(entry.getKey(), addedColoSockets);
    }
  }

  private List<SocketInfo> connect(DatacenterEnum dc, List<String> addresses, int socketType) {
    List<SocketInfo> socketList = new ArrayList<>();
    // ... some code here
    return socketList;
  }

  // called from multiple reader threads to get next live available socket
  public Optional<SocketInfo> getNextSocket() {
    Optional<SocketInfo> liveSocket =  getLiveSocket(liveSocketsByDc.get(DatacenterEnum.CORP));
    return liveSocket;
  }

  private Optional<SocketInfo> getLiveSocket(final List<SocketInfo> listOfEndPoints) {
    if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(listOfEndPoints)) {
      Collections.shuffle(listOfEndPoints);
      for (SocketInfo obj : listOfEndPoints) {
        if (obj.isLive()) {
          return Optional.of(obj);
        }
      }
    }
    return Optional.absent();
  }

  // update CHM map every 30 seconds
  private void updateSockets() {
    Map<DatacenterEnum, ImmutableList<String>> socketsByDc = TestUtils.SERVERS;

    for (Entry<DatacenterEnum, ImmutableList<String>> entry : socketsByDc.entrySet()) {
      List<SocketInfo> liveSockets = liveSocketsByDc.get(entry.getKey());
      List<SocketInfo> liveUpdatedSockets = new ArrayList<>();
      for (SocketInfo liveSocket : liveSockets) {
        Socket socket = liveSocket.getSocket();
        String endpoint = liveSocket.getEndpoint();

        boolean sent = ....;

        boolean isLive = sent ? true : false;

        // is this right here? or will it cause any race condition?
        SocketInfo state = new SocketInfo(socket, liveSocket.getContext(), endpoint, isLive);
        liveUpdatedSockets.add(state);
      }
      // update map with new liveUpdatedSockets
      liveSocketsByDc.put(entry.getKey(), liveUpdatedSockets);
    }
  }
}
```

**Question:**

Is my above code thread safe and there is no race condition in `updateSockets()` and `getNextSocket()` method?

In my `updateSockets()` method, I extract `List<SocketInfo>` from `liveSocketsByDc` ConcurrentHashMap which was already populated before in `connectToSockets()` method during initialization or next interval of 30 second in `updateSockets()` method and then I am iterating same list `liveSockets` and create a new `SocketInfo` object depending on whether `isLive` is true or false. And then I update `liveSocketsByDc` ConcurrentHashMap with this new `SocketInfo` object. Does this look right? Because from multiple reader threads I am going to call `getNextSocket()` method which inturn calls `getLiveSocket` method which uses same map to get the next available live socket.

I am iterating `liveSockets` list and then creating a new `SocketInfo` object by just changing `isLive` field and other things will stay same. Is this right?

If there is a thread safety issue, what is the best way to fix this?

Comment: No, it's not thread safe. The first violation I found (didn't go further) is that every read gets a shared ArrayList out of the map and shuffles it.

Comment: This question probably fits better on our sister site [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) than it does here.

Comment: @JBNizet I see so how can we fix this in my example?

Comment: Store an unmodifiable list to make sure you never accidentally do that again. And make a copy of the list and shuffle that copy.

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
 List<SocketInfo> liveSockets = liveSocketsByDc.get(entry.getKey());
```

Your different threads are potentially writing/reading the **same** list object in parallel.

So: not thread safe. It doesn't help to have an "outer" thread-safe data structure; when that thread-safe thing contains data ... that is not thread-safe; but then "worked on" in parallel!

Comment: What is the best way to fix this thread safety issue in my code?